# How can I connect to mysql from nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am working on a node JS project with mysql database. I have created a new file db.js that is used to connect to the database. My structure looks like below.

```
- server
  - config
     - db.js
  - index.js
```

### db.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

export default() =>{
    const db = mysql.createConnection ({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'socha'
    });

    // connect to database
    db.connect((err) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log('Connected to database');
    });
}
```

### index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const dbConfig = require('./config/db');
const app = express();
```

My problem is I cannot connect to the db.js file from index.js file.

Can anybody tell me what mistake I have been doing.

Thank You

Comment: Is it throwing any errors?

Comment: it is not throwing any error but I am not getting from db.js as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your index.js and db.js to this.
This should create the connection if DB credentials are correct

**db.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');


const connect = () => {
        const db = mysql.createConnection ({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'socha'
    });

    // connect to database
    db.connect((err) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log('Connected to database');
    });
}


module.exports = {
  connect
}
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const dbConfig = require('./config/db');
const app = express();

// Connecting to db
dbConfig.connect();
```

Comment: Yes that worked for me.. I did import express from 'express';
import dbConfig from './config/db';

const app = express();
dbConfig(); which also worked